# Cannot run the Unisubs (amara) repo on Github

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, amara

- In this repo: https://github.com/pculture/unisubs,
- I followed its "Quick start" but at step 3 I got this error:
  "...
  Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages [7589 kB]
  Fetched 20.8 MB in 53s (391 kB/s)
  W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '`/bin/sh -c apt-get update`' returned a `non-zero code: 100`
"

- I created an issue for that repo but its owner said that it doesn't seem like the repo issue, but the ubuntu packages or docker base image issue. Then he closed this issue.
- Then Mr. Google guided me to add a line of code: "`RUN rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`" before "`RUN apt-get update`" in the `Dockerfile` file. But still no luck. I still got the same error.

Could anyone tell me how I can fix it to run this repo? Thank you so much.

**Update 1**:

Hi, I found the cause of this issue. It's because of my internet provider who bans some download urls. I switched to another internet provider and ran step 3: bin/dev build successfully, although there was another issue at this step "Setting up ca-certificates-java" which I solved using "overlay" machine thanks to this topic: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180 -> But now I come up with another issue at step 4: bin/dev up -> The error is below:
"
Creating unisubs20160121_cache_1
Creating unisubs20160121_queue_1
Creating unisubs20160121_db_1
Creating unisubs20160121_worker_1
Creating unisubs20160121_app_1
Attaching to unisubs20160121_worker_1, unisubs20160121_app_1
worker_1 | /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
unisubs20160121_worker_1 exited with code 2
app_1    | /usr/bin/python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
unisubs20160121_app_1 exited with code 2
"

I guest the command: "bin/dev up" wants to execute file manage.py which does not exist in folder bin/dev. Another weird thing I notice is that after running step 3: "bin/dev build" successfully, there's no new files generated in folder bin/dev. Could anyone please help me to figure this step out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `docker pull ubuntu:14.04` ?  It could be that whichever apt mirror you're hitting has some corrupt metadata. You could also try using a different mirror

Comment: Did it try but still error: Hash Sum mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is probably wrong...

I believe the problem is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pculture/unisubs/blob/staging/Dockerfile) is structured incorrectly.

It's documented in [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) that any `apt-get install` should have an `apt-get update` before it as part of the same `RUN` directive.

The reason for this, as you've discovered, is that if you don't you end up in a situation where the `update` is cached, but the upstream packages have changed, so when you try to install, the build fails.

A temporary solution is to run with `--no-cache` `docker build --no-cache ...`.

The real solution is to fix the Dockerfile.

Comment: I typed: docker build --no-cache=true but it said: docker: "build" requires 1 argument.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by...switching to [SubtitleEdit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/). Not using Unisubs (Amara) project anymore as there's bunch of issues to run it. Thanks all for your answers :).